# Flask socket.io message events in different files

Tags: python, flask-socketio

socketservice.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from backend.database import db

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connection():
    from backend.electionAdministration import syncElections
    syncElections()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

electionAdministration.py:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from bson.json_util import dumps
from backend.socketservice import socketio
from backend.database import db

def syncElections():
    elections = db.elections.find()
    emit('syncElections',dumps(res) , broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('createElection')
def createElection(data):
    db.elections.insert({'title': data["title"]})
    syncElections()
```

The problem is, that the `createElection` event is never being called, when it is within the file `electionAdministration.py`. When I move it into `socketservice.py`, it suddenly works.

But I mean, I cannot put everything into one file, as it will get very messy as the application grows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is import your secondary module in the main module, but you need to do it after the `socketio` variable is created, because if not you will run into circular dependency errors.

Example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from backend.database import db

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connection():
    from backend.electionAdministration import syncElections
    syncElections()

import electionAdministration  # <--- import your events here!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

In addition, you need to consider that your main Python script is not going to be called `socketservice`, because Python always names the top-level script `__main__`. So, if you start the above script as your main script, the second file should import `socketio` as follows:

```
from __main__ import socketio
```

This is a small annoyance with Python, which is made worse when you want to have a script that you sometimes run as a main script, but other times you also want it to be imported by another script. To make the import work in such case, I use the following trick:

```
try:
    from __main__ import socketio
except ImportError:
    from socketservice import socketio
```

Comment: I could swear it was working for a while, but I might have ended up with the event in both files. Anyway, even with the import statement you mentioned, the event is still not being called when it's only in the imported file :(

Comment: Updated my answer with information about `__main__`.

Comment: Hello netik, did you find the solution to this issue ?