# flask_socketio and React Client - send not working

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Hie,

I have a flask server with a React client and I'm using flask_socketio to create a socket and socket.io-client on my React client to connect to it

I'm able to send and receive messages just fine by using the following code on my server:

```
message = {"hello": "world"} 

with app.test_request_context('/'): 
    send (message, broadcast=True, namespace="/")
```

And this code on in my client:

```
import io from "socket.io-client" 

let endPoint = "http://localhost:5000"; 
let socket = io.connect (`${endPoint}`);
```

To connect to the socket and this code to act on messages:

```
useEffect(() => {  

    socket.on ("message", msg => {
        console.log (msg); 
    }) 
}, []);
```

However! When I moved the code sending the messages to another file and then called it like this: (app is a global variable representing my flask app)

```
from app import app 

with app.test_request_context('/'): 
    send ({"hello": "world"}, broadcast=True, namespace="/")
```

The message is no longer received on the client side as before

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to import the "app" from **main** and not from app:

```
from __main__ import app
```

as explained here: 
[Flask socket.io message events in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622408/flask-socket-io-message-events-in-different-files)